# Checking capsLock status

Tags: java, windows, gwt

I am using Java with GWT.
In TextItem(GWT), I want to show the callout if the Caps Lock is on while set focus on there.

Is there any property or trick to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.
Sathya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function 
http://www.csua.berkeley.edu/~jgwang/capslock.htm
as a native Javascript method in GWT

Comment: How are you calling the native method?  I'm calling it like this: checkCapsLock(event.getNativeEvent());  The event is the FocusEvent from a FocusHandler.  I'm getting the runtime message "cannot be cast to FocusHandler".

Comment: checkout this article about JSNI http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html